# Explanation of repeated ASN in an AS path from a RouteViews file

Tags: bgp

From the RouteViews RIB files, I was looking at the snapshot from Nov 06, 2017 at 18:00 UTC. This has to do with this BGP routing misconfiguration -- https://dyn.com/blog/widespread-impact-caused-by-level-3-bgp-route-leak/

```
TIME: 06/30/17 18:00:09
TYPE: TABLE_DUMP_V2/IPV4_UNICAST
PREFIX: 198.45.49.0/24
SEQUENCE: 536125
FROM: 195.66.226.74 AS41695
ORIGINATED: 06/12/17 15:55:45
ORIGIN: IGP
ASPATH: 41695 174 174 3356 2906
NEXT_HOP: 195.66.226.74
AGGREGATOR: AS2906 198.45.49.1
COMMUNITY: 174:21000 174:22013 41695:1000 41695:1003 41695:1103
```

I'm trying to understand what exactly the repeated 174 signifies in the `ASPATH`, and how it relates to this misconfiguration (if it does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASes will often prepend their own AS number multiple times to try to control how neighboring ASes send traffic to it. For example, an AS with multiple paths between it and another AS can prepend its own AS number multiple times for the less desirable paths. This usually results in the neighboring AS to send traffic through the path without the prepending, although a different AS determines its own paths to take, and it can ignore the prepending.